# Django Naive Chat Implementation. Will it work?

Tags: django, database, performance, server, chat

I was asked to make a chat application on django for a special portal where only at a particular time 4 staff users can be talking to 4 selected users from a large (around 500 not all logged in at the same time) user database.

I implemented it using django and ajax with the following details ->

I used the chat model which stores all the chat messages sent to the server till now.Its fields are

1. userto
2. userfrom
3. message

Each user has two states :

1. He can wait for a chat room to get empty which he can be alloted
2. He can be in a chat room and talk with one of the staff users

When in a chat room , using ajax I query all messages in the chat table, and show the messages which belong to the chat. Now a request is sent to the server each 0.5 seconds to update the message list.

Note - Inside a chatroom only the messages between the two users should be displayed

When not in a chat room , The user is redirected to a normal page (which is not real time) and displays all chat rooms that can be joined.
Here the user refreshes the page and only at that time sends the request to the server , which updates the list of the chat rooms.Basically the staff talks to only 1 person at a time.

So basically the following should be the maximum load handled by the server every second ->

1. 16 requests every second from each user(1 request every half second) to update the chat each of which goes through all the chat messages sent till now.
2. At max around 30-50 users will be visiting the portal at any given time , so they may send refresh requests say around 1 per every 4-5 seconds.But here the database query is very small as it has to go through only 4 rows of database ie the chatrooms.

So that gives around 30 requests to the server per second in which 16 are heavy requests which need to go through all chat messages sent by each user till now and 14 light requests which need to query only 4 rows of a database.

This will be deployed in the future on a server (RAM-256 GB upgradable to 1.5 TB , hard disk - 3*1.8 TB) and currently on a server (harddisk - 1900 GB and RAM - (around 128 GB)

I have the following 3 questions:

1. Will my current implementation work properly on the giver server constraints, if not I request

   1. firstly improvements in the current system itself ( like reducing time between requests to update chat or database improvements )
   2. Some better and easily implementable method as I don't have much time to change the complete thing
2. I am implementing an archive chat feature from the staff side so that , only non archived messages will be browsed through in those heavy requests every second, which will reduce the number of messages to be browsed considerably
3. If possible I would like to implement the database in such a way where there are separate tables for each staff and user combo. I don't know how to do this so if there is a way please point me in the right direction.

So that I just have to fetch the messages between a staff and user and just display them , and not go through all messages everytime, that should significantly reduce the load I presume.

I have closely followed the chat implementation on the following link

https://github.com/MiniGunnR/django-jquery-chat-application
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8Gjm858CWg&t=322s

Comment: Have you looked at using django-channels? Polling your database every 0.5s like this seems a bit wasteful, in terms of processing power. django-channels lets your server update the client when (lets say) a message has been received. It adds realtime capabilities to django, and chat applications are a prime candidate for this.

Comment: I saw django channels but there are various things surrounding it,
Firstly it was officially released only with django 1.9 and now I think it has been set up as a independent package and plus I saw many reviews on the net speaking that it is not something that is fully developed till now.

The basic thing was that only 8 people needed to be chatting at a time , thats why I went with rudimentary implementation. With that will it work?

Comment: It's one of those things that you need to test to see if it's going to work. Our chat implementation has around 800 people chatting at a time and our server is quite a low spec machine. There is not much load on our server when we have hundreds of people at once. It's not just a chat app, there are a number of other things going on as well, and chat is our least 'resource hogging' part. I think you'll be fine with your implementation. 8 people chatting at once is not many.

Comment: Can you give some details about your chat implementation?